# Getting child-parent rows from same table; sort by different criteria based on row

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, parent-child

I am using MySQL.  I already have a query that does one important part of this:

Get the newest parent row from the table `comments`, and for each parent comment, get the child's comments and sort by the oldest.  *Note:  There is a column called `parent_id`.  All parent's are `0`, all children, of course, are greater than `0`. 
 Also, it is sorting on a column called `create_date`*

This was very doable because the parent and children are both being sorted on `create_date`, (even if one was ASC and one was DESC).

Now I want to add the option for the users to sort by "top" comments, not just the "newest" as I am doing here:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT c1.*, c1.create_date ac, c1.create_date ap FROM comments c1 
WHERE parent_id = 0 AND c1.profile_id = 582 
UNION 
SELECT c2.*, c2.create_date ac, p.create_date ap FROM comments c2 
JOIN comments p ON c2.parent_id = p.id 
WHERE c2.profile_id = 582 
) c
ORDER BY c.ap DESC, c.ac ASC;
```

So the caveat is now I want to sort the parents by a column called `votes` (DESC) and the children (or comment replies) the same as above: `create_date ASC`.

I have tried sub-querys, `ORDER BY`'s with `CASE` statements and more.  What do I need to do for this one sorting modification?

Note:  Performance is nice, but not the hugest issue here.  Also, I know I can do this with code + looping though an outer query -- but I rather not go that route if possible.

Comment: SELECT c1.*, c1.create_date ac, c1.create_date ap FROM comments c1 
WHERE parent_id = 0 AND c1.profile_id = 582, what is this part doing? is it parent comment or child comment? And I don't understand how you are getting the parent comment? I would have thought, you have a condition like: comment.id = 0, to indicate that comment is a parent... but seams like you have comment.parentId = 0 to indicate that comment is a parent??

Comment: @Sarhang that part gets all of the parents. The SELECT below the union joins the child comments to the parent.

Comment: @kickingLettues, I removed my answer as it was wrong and you have figured out the answer yourself, well done.

Comment: @Sarhang thanks for your help.  I have added my answer, if any feedback, I'd love to hear.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
     SELECT c1.*, c1.vote_count totals, c1.parent_id pa_id, c1.id p_id, c1.create_date ac, c1.create_date ap FROM comments c1 
     WHERE parent_id = 0 AND c1.profile_id = 582 
     UNION 
     SELECT c2.*, p.vote_count totals, p.parent_id pa_id, p.id p_id, c2.create_date ac, p.create_date ap FROM comments c2 
     JOIN comments p ON c2.parent_id = p.id 
     WHERE c2.profile_id = 582 
) c
ORDER BY c.totals DESC, 
CASE
  WHEN c.pa_id = 0 THEN c.p_id
  ELSE c.parent_id
END ASC,
c.ac ASC
```

I just make a new alias column called `totals` that basically assigns the parent's vote count to the child so they will sort together.

Edit:  I also had to add the parent comment's id and parent id for sorting purposes which is used in the new `CASE` statement in the `ORDER BY`